# c# CodeDOM - Initialize array

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm trying to create a simple dll runtime, using CodeDOM. 
I have quite understand what I need to finish this simple test application.

I need to create with CodeDOM object this statement:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>() {"A", "B", ... }
```

I'm just having this statement for declaration of a List of n values, but find nowhere the instructions for reach what I need.

This is my actual code:

```
CodeCompileUnit compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();            
CodeNamespace samples = new CodeNamespace("ClassLibrary1");

compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(TestNamespace);

samples.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));
samples.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System.Collections.Generic"));            
samples.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System.Text"));            

CodeTypeDeclaration _class = new CodeTypeDeclaration("TestClass");

CodeMemberField _field = new CodeMemberField();
_field.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
_field.Name = "_testMember";
_field.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(List<string>));

//This is where I cannot understand how to insert the values
_field.InitExpression = new CodeObjectCreateExpression(new CodeTypeReference(typeof(List<string>)), new CodePrimitiveExpression(64));            

class1.Members.Add(_field);
```

How to initialize a list (or an array) with some default values?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: CodeDOM does **not** support collection initializers, and you won't be able to generate that precise code. In your particular case, you should be able to generate code for `new List<string>(new string[] {"A", "B", ... })` using CodeArrayCreateExpression.

Comment: @MichaelLiu can you provide a few line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, the answer lies in `CodeArrayCreateExpression`.

Here is the completed (working) code snippet:

```
        CodeCompileUnit compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
        CodeNamespace samples = new CodeNamespace("ClassLibrary1");

        compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(samples);

        samples.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));
        samples.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System.Collections.Generic"));
        samples.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System.Text"));

        CodeTypeDeclaration _class = new CodeTypeDeclaration("TestClass");

        CodeMemberField _field = new CodeMemberField();
        _field.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
        _field.Name = "_testMember";
        _field.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(List<string>));

        var initialiseExpression = new CodeArrayCreateExpression(
            new CodeTypeReference(typeof(string)),
            new CodePrimitiveExpression("A"),
            new CodePrimitiveExpression("B"),
            new CodePrimitiveExpression("C"));
        _field.InitExpression = new CodeObjectCreateExpression(new CodeTypeReference(typeof(List<string>)), initialiseExpression);
        _class.Members.Add(_field);
```

The important part is the new `initialiseExpression` variable that defines the array.